# Proper way to deal with string which looks like json object but it is wrapped with single quote

Tags: python, json

By definition the JSON string is wrapped with double quote.

In fact:

`json.loads('{"v":1}')   #works`

`json.loads("{'v':1}")   #doesn't work`

But how to deal with the second statements?
I'm looking for a solution different from eval or replace.
Thanks.

Comment: The second one is not valid JSON. How did you get it?

Comment: Why "different from replace"? This would just work.

Comment: I think it's the wrong approach to allow malformed JSON input. Your interface should be saying "Give me well-formed JSON or I won't work. Period." If you're the one building the input, use `json.dumps` to do so. If others use your interface, tell them to do so.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no control on input side. But, following your advice, I'll recommend the other side to use json.dumps to store json object. Thanks

Comment: If you want to check out why the input is malformed, check out the the grammar rules at http://www.json.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I got your requirements right, but are you looking for something like this?

```
def fix_json(string_):
    if string_[0] == string_[-1] == "'":
        return '"' + string_[1:-1] +'"'
    return string_
```

Example usage:

```
>>> fix_json("'{'key':'val\"'...cd'}'")
"{'key':'val"'...cd'}"
```

**EDIT:** it seems that the humour I tried to have in making the example above is not self-explanatory. So, here's another example:

```
>>> fix_json("'This string has - I'm sure -  single quotes delimiters.'")
"This string has - I'm sure -  single quotes delimiters."
```

This examples show how the "replacement" only happens at the extremities of the string, not within it.

you could also achieve the same with a regular expression, of course, but if you are just checking the starting and finishing char of a string, I find using regular string indexes more readable....

Comment: You should probably read the question again, you seem to have totally misunderstood it. Your code still produces invalid JSON but now with double quotation marks around it - not very useful.

Comment: @Wladimir - you should probably read my answer again too! :) Don't let you distract from the silly example I made (it's a kind of joke): what the function does is to change the outer single quotes to double quotes. I think what you are expecting my function to do (which it doesn't) is to parse a json string, finding out what the strings are in it, and changing their delimiters.

Comment: @Wladimir - absolutely! :) Sense of humour is one of the most cultural-bound aspects or one's personality, I would probably don't get some of your humour either. As far as the **explanation** of what the function does is clear - though - I'm happy!

Answer (score 2):

If you get a mailformed json why don't you just replace the double quotes with single quotes before

```
json.load
```

Comment: To me using replace is not a clean way to accomplish this job....because the string could be something like this {'key':'val"\'...cd'}.

Answer (score 2):

If you cannot fix the other side you will have to convert invalid JSON into valid JSON. I think the following treats escaped characters properly:

```
def fixEscapes(value):
  # Replace \' by '
  value = re.sub(r"[^\\]|\\.", lambda match: "'" if match.group(0) == "\\'" else match.group(0), value)
  # Replace " by \"
  value = re.sub(r"[^\\]|\\.", lambda match: '\\"' if match.group(0) == '"' else match.group(0), value)
  return value

input = "{'vt\"e\\'st':1}"
input = re.sub(r"'(([^\\']|\\.)+)'", lambda match: '"%s"' % fixEscapes(match.group(1)), input)
print json.loads(input)
```

Answer (score 0):

*unfortunately* you have to do this:

```
f = open('filename.json', 'rb')

json = eval(f.read())
```

done!

this works, but apparently people don't like the `eval` function. Let me know if you find a better approach. I used this on some twitter data...

Comment: Now if someone can figure out what search criteria you use to get your twitter data, they can send you a python injection. Tell us more about this project of yours.